# Xubuntu/Ubuntu 16.10 Issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, kernel, xubuntu

Hello I have been using ubuntu and many of its various DE clones for around 10~ years. This is actually similar to an issue I faced when using older hardware in the past.

From version 12.04-16.0.4.1 I have had no problems installing xubuntu on my machine UEFI mode included. My motherboard is a asus sabertooth gen/3 rev 2.0"990fx series chipset SB950" my GPU is a MSI GTX 970....

When I try to run the install either via the live system or the install xubuntu option I am faced with a blank screen... now I have used an old workaround to actually get it to boot when when there is a problem with incompatible or buggy graphics drivers.

I am assuming the noveau GPU drivers are buggy in this update.. but my issue dosnt stop here.. I tether my samsung rugby 4 to my pc and in all previous version of xubuntu I have never had an issue but for some reason in this version of xubuntu it forces my phone into a reset loop as if its getting shorted...

I am guessing this is a kernel issue and would like to know if this is being worked on or if there is a workaround besides having to just setup the mainline kernel...

Comment: Ok so I have confirmed part of this is a kernel related issue not sure exactly what about the default 16.10's 4.8 kernel issue that causes the blank screen but it is fixed by using my own self compiled mainline kernel.. but what isnt fixed by this is the usb problem which causes my tethered samsung rugby 4 phone to constantly reboot...

Comment: I have to assume it has something to do with a change to networking and its present in both Xubuntu and Ubuntu regardless of using my own self compiled mainline kernel... Oh yes using the old 4.4 kernel for xubuntu 16.04.1 also works to fix the need for nomodeset.... for now I have reinstalled 16.04.1 compiled the latest 4.8.5 stable kernel and will wait for a response from the community on how to bypass this usb problem.